# How do I make this code for detecting palindrome in a Linked List cover all cases?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

So, I was solving this problem of detecting a palindrome in a linked list. I came up with the following solution for it:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
        ListNode temp=head;
        boolean [] arr = new boolean[10];
        int count=0;
        if(head==null) return false;
        while(temp!=null)
        {
            if(arr[temp.val]==false)
                arr[temp.val]=true;
            
            else
                arr[temp.val]=false;
            temp=temp.next;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i]==true)
                count++;
        }
        if(count<2)return true;
        return false;

    }
```

Now, the logic behind this solution is correct as far as I can see but it fails for cases like this: [1,0,0], [4,0,0,0,0] etc. How do I overcome this? (Pls dont reply with a shorter method I want to know the reason behind why this fails for certain cases.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all Welcome to StackOverflow!

Because of how simple this problem's solution can be I feel obligated to tell you that a solution with an auxiliary stack is not only easy to implement but also easy to understand. But since you asked why your code fails for certain cases I'll answer that question first. Your code in particular is counting the number of digits that have an odd count.

Although this seems to be what you are supposed to do to detect a palindrome notice that a linked list that looks like 1 -> 1 -> 0 -> 0 is also considered a palindrome under your code because the count is always going to be less than 0.

Your solution works for telling us if it is possible to create a palindrome given a set of digits. Suppose that the question was like "given a linked list tell me if you can rearrange it to create a palindrome" but it does not work for "is this linked list a palindrome".

Comment: I have since identified solutions employing Stringbuilder and stacks too and how they can significantly reduce the line count of the problem....thank you for the help.